# What does mongoose return when a find query is empty?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm setting up a function that searches for a user based on an id and if no user is found, it creates a new one. I have no users yet so the query never returns a user. However, I'm unable to successfully check for this case. What exactly is returned when a `find` query is empty?

```
 User.find(id,(error,user)=>{
        if(error){
          console.log(error);
        }else{
          if(user == [] || user == null || user == undefined || user == {} || user == '[]'){
            User.addUser({"fbID":id,"lastMessage":"[]"},(error,response)=>{
              if(error){
                console.log(error);
              }else{
                console.log(response);
              }
            });
          }else{
            console.log("User exists.");
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for one user, so use `findOne`. And simply do `if (!user) {`. Don't overkill.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First let's consider your conditions:

```
user == [] || user == null || user == undefined || user == {} || user == '[]'
```

1. The `user == []` will always be false. Even `[] == []` is always false.
2. If you're testing `user == null` then you don't need `user == undefined` and vice versa because `null == undefined` is always true (unlike `null === undefined` which is not).
3. `user == {}` will always be false. Even `{} == {}` is always false.
4. `user == '[]'` can be true if `user` literally contains the string `[]` but this will never happen in Mongo

Here is how to check if there was anything found or not:

For `User.find`:

```
User.find({}, (err, users) => {
  // users is an array which may be empty for no results
  if (err) {
    // handle error
    return;
  }
  if (users.length) {
    // there are user(s)
  } else {
    // there are no users
  }
});
```

For `User.findOne`:

```
User.findOne({}, (err, user) => {
  // user is a single document which may be null for no results
  if (err) {
    // handle error
    return;
  }
  if (user) {
    // there is user
  } else {
    // there is no user
  }
});
```

For `User.findById`:

```
User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
  // user is a single document which may be null for no results
  if (err) {
    // handle error
    return;
  }
  if (user) {
    // there is user
  } else {
    // there is no user
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommend reading docs on queries [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

You Should be getting error with results as null.

First thing,
When executing a query with a callback function, you specify your query as a JSON document. The JSON document's syntax is the same as the MongoDB shell. SO I recommend running your queries in Mongod first.

```
User.find({_id: id}, (error, results) =>{})
```

Here is how I accomplished this same function. Note i'm using Body-parser.

```
Login_or_Create: (req,res) => {
    User.findOne({name:req.body.name}, (err, user) => { #
        if(user == null){
            let newUser = new User(req.body);
            newUser.save( (err, savedUser) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    return res.sendStatus(500);
                }else{
                    req.session.user = savedUser;
                    return res.json(savedUser);
                }
            })
        }else{
            req.session.user = user;
            return res.json(user)
        }
    })
},
```

With your code `User.findOne({_id:id} >>>` Or you can keep it the same, but try `User.findById(id, (error, user) =>{})`

Answer (score -1):

For the above comment, Mongoose dropped support for callbacks from its node.js driver as of version 5.0, **you cannot use the callback function**, but you can use async/await or promises(then).

Check; [MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback at Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75649330/mongooseerror-model-findone-no-longer-accepts-a-callback-at-function)