# Connect mongodb and js

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I got error  "throw new MongooseError('Mongoose.prototype.connect() no longer accepts a callback');"

````
const mogoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/?directConnection=true";

const connectToMongo = ()=>{
    mongoose.connect(mogoURI,()=>{
        console.log("Connected to Mongo Successfully");
    })



}

module.exports = connectToMongo;```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback at Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75649330/mongooseerror-model-findone-no-longer-accepts-a-callback-at-function)

Answer (score 0):

what version of mongoose are you using? As the error says the connect method does not take a callback function. The second argument to the function is now an options object you can pass, but now the third parameter is the callback function.

doc: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#callback

in your case if you just remove that callback it should work, just do:

`mongoose.connect(mogoURI)`

Answer (score 0):

As the error tells you, the callback is not supported anymore in Mongoose `connect()` function. Instead, the function returns a promise where you can handle it either for successful or error cases

```js
mongoose.connect(mogoURI)
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to Mongo Successfully"))
  .catch(error => handleError(error));
```

Better way is to use JS await keyword:

```js
try {
  await mongoose.connect(mogoURI);
  console.log("Connected to Mongo Successfully");
} catch (error) {
  handleError(error);
}
```