# MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback (counting Scheme)

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

[image: This is the error code im getting]

[image: This is the code]

this is really confusing me and im not sure why they have removed this option or what to replace it with im aware it has been removed but i don't know how to fix it

If anyone can help that would be fantastic

i have tried replacing it and adjusting it but to no good

Comment: Hi Ryan, welcome to Stack Overflow. The source code and console output inside images are hard to read and cannot be copied directly. When including code or errors, you should use Stack Overflow's built-in code formatting option.

Answer (score 1):

Mongo dropped support for callbacks from its node.js driver as of version 5.0 in favour of a Promise-only public API. Mongoose also dropped callback support in v7 so `findOne()` and other methods now always return a promise: [MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback at Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75649330/mongooseerror-model-findone-no-longer-accepts-a-callback-at-function)

**async / await**

```js
async function tetsing(guilId) {
  try {
    const data = await countingScheme.findOne({ GuildID: guilId });
    /* ... */
  } catch(err) {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

**then / catch**

```js
countingScheme.findOne({ GuildID: guilId })
  .then((data) => { /* ... */ })
  .catch((err) => { /* ... */ });
```

**asynchronous**

```js
countingScheme.findOne({ GuildID: guilId })
  .then(async (data) => { /* ... */ })
  .catch((err) => { /* ... */ });
```