# i m traying to update user profile information Database

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, multer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwBeA.png)router.post('/profile/update', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
const userId = req.user._id;

```
userModel.findById(userId, function(err, user) {
if (err) {
  return next(err);
}

// Update user profile details
user.username = req.body.username || user.username;
user.email = req.body.email || user.email;
user.contact = req.body.contact || user.contact;
user.name = req.body.name || user.name;

// Save the updated user
user.save(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err);
  }

  res.redirect("/profile");
});
```

});
});

i m traying to update user profile information Database but this code is not work & send me some error:

- **" Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id') "**[When i click update button show this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcnyz.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback at Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75649330/mongooseerror-model-findone-no-longer-accepts-a-callback-at-function)

Answer (score 0):

as the error says, you can't use callbacks anymore in Mongoose, you must use async-await instead and try-catch to handle any errors that may occur
-or you may consider another way for handling errors-:

```
try {
const user = await userModel.findById(userId);
response.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      user,
      
    }
}
} catch (error) {
    response.status(404).json({
      status: "fail",
      messaga: error.message,
      
    })
```

don't forget to mark your handler with `async` keyword